# Why table name in double quotes with trailing typo is valid syntax

Tags: postgresql

I entered the following query into my Postgres terminal, with an accidental `l` after the trailing double quote and before the semi-colon. I expected a syntax error, but instead I got query results:

```
select * from "myTable"l;
```

And in fact, I can put anything I want after the trailing double quote and I still don't get a syntax error:

```
select * from "myTable"asdkjh;
```

I checked what I thought would be the [relevant docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) for how double quoted strings should be formatted, but it didn't mention this.

So, why does this work?

Comment: That trailing garbage is an "Alias". You can do: `SELECT asd123.* FROM "myTable" asd123` (the space doesn't matter here). Aliases are important for self joins like `SELECT t1.id, t2.name FROM table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.parent_id = t2.id` The keyword `AS` is optional as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `l` or `asdkjh` is taken as a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES).

The keyword `AS` to introduce an alias is optional, so you instead of `from foo as x` can also write `from foo x`.

`from foox` however would indeed be an error as that would be taken as a complete table name. As you have used a quoted identifier, it is clear where the identifier ends and the next identifier starts - thus no whitespace is required between the identifier and the alias.

So, `from "myTable"asdkjh` is identical to `from "myTable" as asdkjh`

---

However, `from "myTable""some_alias"` would be an error as it is taken as a single identifier - to include a double quote in a quoted identifier, you write two quotes, so `"myTable""some_alias"` references a table named `myTable"some_alias`